# Websphere application server logging in SystemOut.log

Tags: websphere, rad

By default, log, error, and trace information for all processes and applications on a process server is written to the SystemOut.log, But our requirement is to only log Request and Responses . Is there any setup in admin console to do this?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: So you're not asking about your application's logging, but about *reducing* what WebSphere itself logs to SystemOut?

Answer (score 0):

When WebSphere starts, it designates the `SystemOut.log` file as the file into which all `System.out` prints will go to. Therefore, whenever any code is issuing, for example, `System.out.println`, the output will end up going into `SystemOut.log` - and that is true for both your application code *and* WebSphere's internal code.

To achieve the effect that you're looking for, consider using some logging framework, such as [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) or Java's standard logging API.

Comment: Still aren't there simple way to redirect just exceptions with stacktrace per module logs?

Comment: There isn't such feature built into WAS as of yet. I'm pretty sure there won't be, either. What you're asking for is exactly what logging frameworks such as `slf4j` are for.